# Lottery game w/ replacement

Tags: statistics

My professor has given us a question that is confusing me. Here it is verbatim:

> A state lottery game is played by selecting three numbers between 0 and 9, inclusive, with replacement. The winning numbers are selected in the same way. You win if your numbers match the winning numbers in any order.Find the total number of ways the winning numbers can be selected.

He is telling us the answer is 220, but with how this is worded, it differentiates "winning numbers" or numbers drawn and "your numbers". It's asking how many ways can the winning number be selected. I see how if the winning numbers were selected, then there would be 6 ways for YOUR number to be selected, but I dont understand how 220 is selected. 10^3 = 1,000, but I'm not sure how to adjust for duplicates.

Comment: What this is supposed to mean is that the random selection $3,1,4$ represents  the same winning number as $4,3,1$ etc., but is different from the winning number corresponding to the random selection $2,4,2$, for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will translate what your professor means (deriving it from the given answer):

"How many different triplets of winning numbers are there?"

As ordering does not matter you have

- $\color{blue}{10}$ triplets with only one number (e.g. $(1,1,1)$)
- $\color{blue}{10\cdot 9}$ triplets with exactly two equal numbers (e.g. $(1,2,1)$)
- $\color{blue}{\binom{10}{3}}$ triplets with three different numbers (e.g. $(1,2,3)$)

All together
$$\color{blue}{10} + \color{blue}{10\cdot 9} + \color{blue}{\binom{10}{3}} = 220$$

p.s.:

The wording of the question is indeed a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom{10}3$ ways of choosing 3 distinct numbers, each of which can be drawn in 6 equally probable ways

There are $2\binom{10}2$ ways of having two of one number and one of another each of which can be drawn in 3 equally probable ways

There are $\binom{10}1$ ways to have three of a kind each of which can be drawn in 1 equally probable way

$$ \binom{10}3+2\binom{10}2 + \binom{10}1=220$$

$$6 \times \binom{10}3+3\times2\binom{10}2 + 1 \times\binom{10}1=1000$$